# Django custom DateField: to_python() to save two fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form field that I'm using for my model (which contains two DateField fields)

```
class DateRangeField(forms.DateField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            values = value.split(' - ')
            from_date = super(DateRangeField, self).to_python(values[0])
            to_date = super(DateRangeField, self).to_python(values[1])
        except:
            raise ValidationError(_("Invalid input"))

        return from_date, to_date
```

and in my form, I'm only showing one field

```
class EventDateRangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    daterange = DateRangeField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = []
```

and my model

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    start_day = models.DateField(blank=False,
                                 null=False)
    end_day = models.DateField(blank=False,
                               null=False)
```

how would I process the form so that when the form is valid, it will save `from_date` and `to_date` to `start_day` and `end_day`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the way to do it. What you need is *one* field, but two widgets. You can use [MultiValueField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield) in conjunction with [MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget) to achieve this.

Comment: Having one field will make it harder to do queries on both start_dat and end_day separately

Comment: I didn't say one model field, I meant one form field. But to be honest I have no idea why you don't just use two fields in your form.

Comment: I'm using http://www.daterangepicker.com/ and trying to parse the field input and save it into `start_date` and `end_date`